# Call web-service's object's method

Tags: c#, java, web-services

I have a web-service that returns a custom object, but now I want to call some of the object's methods e.g. to change some of it's values (but also for other needs), but how can I do that?

Do I have to set the object up as a web-service or how?

The web-service is created in Java and the client is created in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but now I want to call some of the object's methods to change some of it's values, but how can I do that?

This will depend on the protocol you are using but because you mentioned Java service and .NET client I assume SOAP. This is not possible with SOAP. There are no methods in the generated client proxy. It's a POCO. You could modify the properties of this client object and pass it to some server method for processing.

Comment: Yes, it is SOAP, but what if I then create a method in the Web-service to e.g. edit the values of the object, will it then work, if I also send the object as a parameter?

Comment: @The87Boy, yes, that's exactly what you should do in order to pass the updated object to the server.

Comment: I meant, if the web-service method could also update the object or add other objects to the 1st object's List, but I think it can

Comment: @The87Boy, once you invoke some web method to fetch the object, the service returns some instance and no longer has any control over this object. This object is reconstructed on the client. It's a different instance.

Comment: Yes, but if I use it as a parameter to the web-service's method to add some data to the object, the object will be changed on the client too or?

Comment: @The87Boy, no it won't, unless the server method returns the new changed object.

Comment: Thanks for the help, now I know how to do it :D